# Pocket chrome extension does not highlight already bookmarked articles?

Tags: pocket

[I am using getpocket.com chrome extension](https://getpocket.com/chrome/).

**Problem**

Suppose I have bookmarked a stackoverflow.com post. It highlights it in the current chrome tab.But If I reopen the same link in another tab. It does not highlight it. But It should because It is already present in the bookmarked list.

**It could be a bug. How can I report this problem to getpocket.com developers.**

My system details

- Google chrome
- chrome extension for google chrome(Getpocket.com).

What have I tried ?

[I have tried to report this error to getpocket.com team through this page](https://help.getpocket.com/category/847-category#contactModal)

**Is this a known bug?**

Answer (score 1):

I send this problem to pocket team.

I got a reply from their support team.

```
Thanks for contacting Pocket Support!

I'm sorry to share that showing the Pocket icon red if you're visiting an already saved page is not a feature we offer at the moment. It would be great to add it in the future and we have definitely received a lot of feedback regarding having this available in all our extensions.

However, keep in mind, if the same URL is saved twice in Pocket, it will not save the item twice but will push the item to the top of your List.

That being said, I have submitted your request into our tracking system. This helps the team prioritize most requested features we receive.

Thanks for helping us improve Pocket!
```